# How to create a Selenium 2 Page Object for a menu item that has different items?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am looking to create a Selenium page object for the menu bar of our application.  However, the menu items will be different based on the license that the customer has (about 70% will be the same throughout). I am looking at a couple of approaches (I'm using Java):

1. Create all the methods for all the possible menu items in once class, and then just depend on the test case writer to use the correct methods.
2. Create a different page object for each different license (about 5 as of right now).

Which one would be better in the long term?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same situation for my current job. I use the option #1 as it is the most maintable on the long term. Others solutions will add extra complexity which is not justified.

I'm always testing with "full" licence (the operator can do anything). Then, I have some specific tests to test the GUI is only showing what it is supposed to show with limited licence.

The page object I use will fail if called on a menu that does not exist on the screen (something that turn my test cases red). There are methods on my framework to determine the presence (or not) of a menu.

Note: If you are testing the security of your software (to ensure the operator cannot gain extra access), you need to use other technique. For such test you have to bpass the GUI and "attack" your server directly.

Comment: Thanks! I guess method #1 is what I will go with.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an enumerator for the license types then pass that enum into your method calls on the Page Object?  The method could then use if/else or a switch to return appropriate values or take appropriate action based on the given license.

Comment: Thanks! I guess method #1 is what I will go with.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Java Inheritance
Create a class with the basic account and extend it for complex accounts.
See example here: [Java docs: An Example of Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)